# Unable to authenticate with Looker API on subsequent requests

Tags: looker

I am having an issue in that I am able to authenticate into my instance's [Looker](http://www.looker.com) API endpoint (:19999), but on subsequent requests to pull data I get failed auth message.

How does Looker know then that I am authenticated if I'm not passing the client/secret keys on subsequent requests?

Answer (score 3):

Looker's API authentication endpoint returns an access token to use on subsequent API requests. Access tokens expire after 1 hour, at which point a new access token must be obtained.

Example:

```
$ curl -X POST "https://mylookerhost:19999/api/3.0/login?client_id=myclientid&client_secret=myclientsecret
{"access_token":"someaccesstoken","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

`someaccesstoken` is then passed as a header on each API call:

```
$ curl --header "Authorization: token someaccesstoken" https://mylookerhost:19999/api/3.0/user
```

Or as a URL parameter:

```
$ curl https://mylookerhost:19999/api/3.0/user?access_token=someaccesstoken
```